# What is additional "onto" button in TortoiseGit Rebase?

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit

In TortoiseGit->Rebase window has these two selectors :
[image]

What is the purpose of `Onto` selector, while in `Upstream` you already select the branch you are rebasing onto.

Comment: Did you read [the doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---ontoltnewbasegt) about the option? Is it a question about the option itself or about its implementation in TortoiseGit?

Comment: If is _connected_ to the `--onto` rebase option, it would be what branch would be used to place all commits (between `upstream..-rebase-branch`) on top of it.

Comment: @RomainValeri I wanted to know whether it was same in Tg (as a checkbox), and now I've found out it is same. thanks for comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onto option can be used to rebase some commits that are between the branch and the upsteam onto some other branch.

Onto in the Git docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---ontoltnewbasegt